# Android Service stopped working

Tags: android, service

I have implemented service in my application. It worked fine with android 2.3.5 and lower SDK devices, recently i bought android4.0 device and when i test the application, service stopped working and i tested Running services from settings(Settings -> Applications -> Running Service) there for my application its showing 0 process and 1 services (Restarting). When i check the logcat, i got the following error

Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x10 } to com.xxxxx.yyyyy requires 
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED due to sender null (uid 1000)

Whats the issue? Please help me to solve this problem.

My Manifest.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxxx.yyyy"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.3" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxxx.yyyy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />       
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />    

<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".ApplicationStart"
    android:configChanges="locale" >
    <activity 
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity 
        android:name=".ThanksScreen" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>    

    <receiver android:name=".MyStartupIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".services.CallService">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xxxx.yyyy.services.CallService" />
    </intent-filter>

    </service>

</application>
```

Comment: `requires android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` says all you need. Have you set the permission? Show us your manifest!

Comment: I added that permission</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>

Comment: Please help me. More over im getting some more warning messages in logcat like the follwoing                  Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone

Comment: onStartCommand(), But the thing is, Its working fine with 2.3.5 SDK. making issues only with 4.0.

Comment: Following method im using for starting a service.                             Intent callService = new Intent();
callService.setAction("com.xxx.yyy.ServicesActivity");
context.startService(callService);

Comment: @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
 {
  return null;
 }

 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
 {
 
  return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
 } Any suggestions or help please?

Comment: Please publish your **entire** manifest, by editing your question and adding it there, formatted as source code.

Comment: And please DON'T post code in a comment. Unreadable and unwanted! Put the code in the question...

Comment: did u resolve it @AndroDev?